# Use Sql for manual testing

Tags: manual-testing

I have some interview in manual testing. Can someone guide me which type of question asked in SQL. Will I use SQL queries in manual testing?

Comment: Yes, it is, if you test something with a database. Generic skills are useful. Learn some.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand the question... are you suggesting that SQL is (usually) an automation function?

Anyway, they'll likely ask if you can interrogate a database (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.) and write basic queries like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name="Jeetu";` or whatever.

If you ever have to write a SQL query then it's, by definition, a manual test.